# Identity with binomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

Does there exist a closed formula for $$\underset{n=1}{\overset{N-1}{\sum}}\dbinom{N+n}{n}?$$ I've searching on wikipedia but I haven't found this kind of sum.

Comment: By changing the summation limits to the more appropriate values $0$ and *N*, we get a certain sequence of integers, which can be found in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org), representing $\displaystyle{2N+1\choose N+1}$. Now that we actually know what it is that we have to prove, we might as well do it by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sum is equal to
$$ \frac{N}{N+1}{2N \choose N}-1.$$
**Proof**: Consider a more general identity
$$\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}{N+n \choose n} =\frac{M}{N+1}{N+M \choose M}, $$
which can be proved by induction on $M$.